# How to reinstall xp from Grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

My friend installed Ubuntu along side windows xp so I could dual boot, after a while I decided to delete the Ubuntu partition unaware that you need the xp recovery disk or something like that to fix windows. So every time I start my computer the grub rescue prompt appearers so is there a way for booting window from grub rescue without the window xp recovery disk?

Comment: You need to have the legit Windows XP disc. There *should* be a repair option.

Comment: If I was to get a legitimate disk how would I boot it up from grub?

Answer (score 0):

When you open your computer there will be a logo of your motherboard manufacturer for example "Asus". When you see that then spam the ESC key. When the logo disapeers then you will see like a BIOS interface menu. Select "Boot Menu". There you should see your CD drive, for mine it is CD-DRIVE. BEFORE YOU SELECT THAT insert your CD, when you insert it they press enter on CD-DRIVE. Then it should boot into the disc. –